# Is this implementation of malloc a bump allocator?

Tags: c, malloc, allocator

I recently wrote a small `malloc` and was wondering if it was a bump allocator. I wonder this because (correct me if I am wrong) I believe the actual `malloc` (while using `mmap` instead of `sbrk`) uses the same technique (sort of), but a bump allocator just increments the heap location. Here is my code:

```c
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>
#include <unistd.h>

#define word_size sizeof(intptr_t)
#define align(n) ((n + word_size - 1) & ~(word_size - 1))

void* my_malloc(size_t size) {
    void* p = sbrk(0);
    if (sbrk(align(size)) == (void*) -1)
        return NULL; // failed
    return p;
}

int main() {
    int* foo = (int*) my_malloc(1);
    *foo = 100;
    printf("%d\n", *foo);
}
```

Comment: I don't know that this is a bump allocator because I don't see where everything is freed up all at once.  I would imagine the *first* allocation would save the return from `sbrk(0)`, which defines the start of the quasi-arena, and the free operation would put that value back with `brk(oldaddr)`.

Comment: @SteveFriedl -- If that were true, would this be a bump allocator?

Comment: Mostly yes, I would think so, though the whole topic is new to me.  The idea behind a bump allocator seems to be that you just "bump" the end of memory forward to handle each request, but you cannot free things up one item at a time - you free everything at once.  I've seen a reference that suggests you need to know how many requests have been made, but I don't see how that's useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I had never heard the term "bump allocator" before, but the concept is straightforward.

It's a really naive allocator that can be very fast due to the tiny amount of housekeeping involved, but you have to live with a pretty heavy constraint: there's no "free" operation for individual request - you just destroy the whole thing.

In your case, you're calling `sbrk(0)` to get the first address at the end of the program's whole data segment - this will be the return value - then "bump" the end of memory with `sbrk(nbytes)` after suitably rounding it up.

This means that the program's data space just grows up for each request, and trying to free something doesn't make any sense because you can't just put a hole in the address space (well, there's probably some funky VM stuff that would work, but that gets complicated).

```
static void *bump_arena_start = 0;

void* my_malloc(size_t size) {
    void* p = sbrk(0);

    if (bump_arena_start == 0) bump_arena_start = p;

    if (sbrk(align(size)) == (void*) -1)
        return NULL; // failed
    return p;
}

void destroy_bump_arena(void)
{
    if (bump_arena_start) brk(bump_arena_start);
}
```

This would probably be a bump allocator, but it would be a **terrible** one for a bunch of reasons.

First: it assumes that *nobody else* is allocating memory, it would have to override all other operations: `malloc`, `C++ new`, everything in the C runtime, etc.

Imagine what would happen if you're doing your own thing with the break, and then some *other* function calls `sbrk()` to allocate some memory. Now they are in the middle of your arena but you mostly don't know it.  So far no problem, but as soon as you go to destroy your arena, it kills everything else.

The way you'd actually use such a thing is when you have a lot of tiny allocations that you don't want to keep track of and can release all at once, so you might use the system allocator (`malloc()`) and ask for a large-enough chunk to handle your needs - let's call it 32kbytes - and stuff this into some object representing this bump arena.

You allocate lots of little bits here and there, do whatever task you need to do, then destroy all of it by freeing that initial 32-kbyte chunk.

The thing is: you have to be **super careful** that you don't let one of these pointers escape to other parts of the system, because they aren't allowed to live beyond the lifetime of your arena.

This is just a really specialized use case that's probably not generally useful, and unless you're doing embedded work (where you are essentially controlling your own runtime), you couldn't really do one with the system break this way.

Side note: you can get into trouble with alignment if you have objects larger than the size of an integer pointer. What if you did this?

```
   int      *foo1 = my_malloc(sizeof(int));       // 8 bytes (usually)
   __int128 *foo2 = my_malloc(sizeof(__int128));  // 16 bytes
```

The naive alignment would put the int on an 8-byte boundary, but so would the 128-bit value (which is 16 bytes), not aligned to its own size; on some platforms that's probably an error, and it's almost always inefficient.

To do it right you'd query the current next-value via `sbrk(0)` and insure *it* was aligned properly for the size, possibly bumping up the break a bit.

**EDIT**: I have looked into this a bit more, and it's pretty clear that your example doesn't quite count as a bump allocator. Here's why.

The memory system not only keeps track of the "next" pointer, but how many allocations have been performed, and it supports a pseudo-free operation that ignores the pointer value but just decrements the allocation counter.

If the allocation counter ever reaches zero, this means nobody else has any of that memory, so it can free everything by rewinding the break to the initial value, essentially starting over with a clean slate.

To use this properly you'd have to really be careful about your deallocations, and a double-free could be very painful.

Really useful reference: https://os.phil-opp.com/allocator-designs/

**EDIT2** - a bit more about alignment per request.

You have to have at least some awareness of alignment no matter what platform you're on, because even if the platform allows unaligned access to memory, it's almost always slower.

The super easy way to always get it right is to figure out the largest possible scalar object supported on the platform, and use that as your alignment modulo, perhaps `__int128`. If you're always rounding up to the nearest 16 bytes, you'll pretty much never run into an alignment issue (plus it's easy).

But it's also space-inefficient: if you're allocating space for a two-byte `short`, it will waste the 14 bytes after it. That might be no big deal in your application, or it might be a thing.

I have never written a memory allocator myself, so I'm doing a lot of handwaving here, but anybody using a bump allocator has some specialized requirements and is probably OK with making specialized requests.

So: I could imagine an allocator that takes not just the size, but also the alignment required, and it would take the `sbrk(0)` pointer and round *that* up the required alignment, save that as the return value, then call `sbrk(size)` to bump the end marker.

Note that you're not aligning to the size of the allocation, but only the size of the low-level item: asking for an array of 20 `short` values means you're asking for 40 bytes but with an alignment of 2, and 100 bytes for a string means you just take the next 100 bytes w/o any alignment.

```
void *my_malloc(size_t nbytes, size_t align = 8)
{
    void *p = sbrk(0);
    p += round up but too hard to think on Friday
    sbrk(nbytes);
    num_allocations++;
    return p;
}
```

This way, if you don't give an alignment size, it makes the same safe assumption you did, but you could always ask if you wanted to be special.

Again: I'm mostly just making this up, I've never had to think about it this way, but I do know that if I'm working on a memory-constrained platform such as an Arduino with RAM measured in *kilobytes*, you have to think about this.

Comment: Just a small question before I mark as the correct answer: The aligning that I'm doing-- does it really help in this case? Btw, +1-- nice answer.

Comment: I've expanded on my post. Yes, you absolutely have to think about alignment, because most platforms do not let you access scalar values on non-aligned boundaries (say, reading an `int` stored at an odd address).  Some platforms do allow it, but it incurs a lot of performance penalties.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, my implementation does the alignment correctly?

Comment: I would say yes.